# How can I change the double-tap zoom in the Android browser?

Tags: stock-browser

I like to use double-tap to zoom in on web pages with small text. (Multitouch pinching has been hard for me to get the hang of.)

It very often zooms too far, though. Is there a way I can get it to zoom in a little less on a double-tap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in the browser settings.

In the default browser, this is found in `Menu | More | Settings | Default Zoom`. Options are "medium" (the default), "far", and "close".